# Override css style from child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

how can I override this css rule:

**Css:**

```
.menu ul>li>a{
color: black;
}
```

I need to change color to blue.
I tried:

```
a.selected{
color : blue;
}
```

```css
.menu ul>li>a {
  color: black;
}
a.selected {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="selected">Test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But it doesnt work. Thank you in advance

Marek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change a.selected to .menu ul>li>a.selected

```css
  .menu ul>li>a{
color: black;
}
   .menu ul>li>a.selected{
color: blue;
  }
```

```html
 <nav class="menu">
    <ul >
        <li>
            <a class="selected">Test</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I need:) clean solution without !important workround.

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu ul>li>a.selected{
  color: blue;
}
```

You could also use !important to override but its generally regarded as bad practise

Answer (score 0):

use `!important` it overrides it with the value you have given You can know more about !important here [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

```css
.menu ul>li>a{
color: black;
}


a.selected{
color : blue !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <ul >
        <li>
            <a class="selected">Test</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```